# Unable to get the token in firebase cloud messaging application

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying to implement firebase cloud messaging service in my application.
Below is my code for the script tag in HTML.

```
   var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBcfYNuvHobyGTY6EcQ86TJVPsPRW5Xcts",
      authDomain: "test-8c53c.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://test-8c53c.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "test-8c53c.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "144847525550"
};

   firebase.initializeApp(config);
   const  messaging = firebase.messaging();
   messaging.requestPermission().then(function(){
      console.log('have permition');
      console.log(messaging.getToken());
      return messaging.getToken().then(function (token) {
        console.log(token+"hii");
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error occured:'+err);
    });
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log('error occure'+err);
});
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payLoad){
    const tittle = 'Hello World';
    const option = {
        body : payLoad.data.status
    }
    return self.registration.showNotification(tittle,option);
});
```

When I run this code in the browser it generates the following error in the browser:

> FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service    worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).

there is another issue that when I try to run by clicking on HTML file token value is returned as null.

Someone, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: It looks like either you forgot to create `firebase-messaging-sw.js` or it's in a place the library isn't looking. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673265/firebase-service-worker-not-found-while-using-gwt-404-error

Comment: I have created a file named as firebase-messaging-sw.js in the same directory only.

Comment: The 404 is a clear indication that your web server is not finding the file that the FCM library requests. You should be able to see the same request in your web server logs.