# FCM Push notifications works locally but not on server

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been struggling to make push notifications work.
I am recieving the following error

> ; FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).

I have already tried to google and applied https://stackoverflow.com/a/42264578/5192105

But still it works locally but not on the [server](https://mobile-app.golocall.com/api/src/public/fcm_web).
The `js` file `firebase-messaging-sw.js` exists in the path:https://mobile-app.golocall.com/api/src/public/firebase-messaging-sw.js

I have used `slim-php` as backend framework.

Please help me out in resolving the error.

Answer (score 1):

It tries to find the service worker file on the root of the application; hence the application tries to load

https://mobile-app.golocall.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js

while the actual file is located at

https://mobile-app.golocall.com/api/src/public/firebase-messaging-sw.js

**EDIT:**
You may be able to import the service worker like this:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to declare your own service worker.

Here is a link to more information on the topic:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Comment: Is there any way i can provide the service worker file path